# "hadn't been working" vs "wasn't working" vs "didn't work" vs "wasn't worked"

Tags: past-tense

Would you please explain the differences among these sentences?

> Ian hadn't been working at the factory long when he was made a
>   manager.
>
> Ian wasn't working at the factory long when he was made a manager.
>
> Ian didn't work at the factory long when he was made a manager.
>
> Ian wasn't worked at the factory long when he was made a manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ***when*** fixes the ["narrative (reference) time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narration) as being the time at which he was made a manager.

Since your initial clause refers to a time ***before*** that (he was working there before he was made a manager), you need to refer to it using Past Perfect Continuous (the first version - *Ian **hadn't been** working at the factory long when he was made a manager*).

The second and third versions would be valid if we change ***when*** to ***before***, but the last one is simply ungrammatical - we don't inflect multiple elements (***wasn't*** and ***worked*** here) for tense when they're both part of the same "compound verb".

Comment: The reason that there's a difference between **when** and **before** is that **before** is enough to fix the first clause before the second, so we have more choice of tenses- past simple or past continuous. On the other hand, **when** does not fix clause 1 before clause 2, so we need to use past perfect in clause 1, to fix it before clause 2.

Comment: @JavaLatte: I *think* you're right there, but I'm not sure how that plays out when we consider non-negated contexts. In constructions like *He had been working there long before they promoted him* it seems ***long before*** is a single compound element modifying the first clause, whereas in OP's versions they're two completely separate elements (only ***long*** refers back to the first clause, ***before*** refers forward).